# Unable to select page contents through class in jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery-mobile

I'm unable to select page contents through class in [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

`$('div[data-role="content"]');` works fine

`$('div.ui-content');` only selects a few

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile adds the class when it enhances the page. You might be calling the selector before the enhancement is done (I won't guess no more, it's your app ;) )

the correct way to get all the content nodes is:

```
$("div:jqmData(role='content')")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should omit the blank, not

```
$('div .ui-content');
```

but

```
$('div.ui-content');
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the behavior is the same. What's the difference between "div .ui-content" and "div.ui-content"?

Comment: I Just checked my project, I always get the same amount with both selectors. As the class ui-content is set by jQuery Mobile, I assume that your HTML does not correspond to the jQuery Mobile way, see http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html. Maybe add your HTML at jsfiddle and link it.